# How to make textbox confirm if correct number entered?

Tags: vba

I'm trying to make a message box based game that requires the player to find hidden codes within the game. My problem is that I don't know how to make the textbox make a popup that says "Congratulations you have entered the correct codes".
I'm also trying to have it use 3 numeric codes.

How would I make all 3 of the textboxes confirm if the codes entered were correct?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the following article on how to ask a question on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . At a minimum, we need you to show us your code and tell us what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by Textbox pop-up?

Do you meant to use a messagebox?
It can be done easily using the below syntax;

```
MsgBox(prompt[, buttons] [, title] [, helpfile, context])
```

More info from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445082(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: I mean by if the user enters the correct code into a textbox, the textbox will make the message box appear. I know how to do the message box, I just don't know how to get the textbox to check if the correct code was entered.

Comment: Unclear question. If you want to compare the value entered and the correct code, you can simply use `if statement`